# What is the difference between having parameters within super and the init parentheses .... super().__init__()

Tags: python, class, oop, init, super

I understand that the concept of `super().__init__()` is to do with inheritance and I have seen code with parameters within `init`. However, I came across a code sample that had this:

```
class Maze(tk.Tk, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Maze, self).__init__()
```

the parameters are now within the `super` parenthesis. What is the difference and why may one be used over the other? Thank you

Comment: Are you using Python3? If so, there is no difference, except that the interpreter does that magic for you when you call super()

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I think they're asking the difference between `super(Maze, self).__init__()` and `super().__init__(Maze, self)`, but I may be wrong...

Comment: Yes using python3. So writing super().init__(Maze, self)__ would be equivalent ?

Comment: @HimansuOdedra No, try both, the former works the later doesn't.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes correct I am asking that

Comment: @HimansuOdedra no, in python 3 `super(Maze, self).__init__()` and `super().__init__()` are the same.

Comment: And in python 2, [the arguments are required](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). So the code example you found may also be using python 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the original way `super()` was intended to work:

```
super(Maze, self).__init__()
```

This is also the only way that it did work in Python 2.

### So, why the arguments?

You want to call `__init__()` of the class which is the *super* class if `Maze` (probably `tk.Tk`), bound to `self`. To do that, you have to pass the arguments `Maze` and `self` to `super`, so that it knows what to do.

**What does it actually do?**

`super(Maze, self).__init__` has to determine `type(self)` to extract the MRO from it, i.e. the order in which classes are inherited from one another.

Then, in that list, it finds the class which is just above `Maze` and looks for an `__init__` in that class or any class above it. When it finds it, it bounds the `__init__` init method to `self` (i.e. fixes its first argument, so you don't have to pass it).

You could implement that version of `super` yourself. It would be something like this:

```
class my_super:
    def __init__(self, cls, obj):
        self.cls = cls
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattribute__(self, method_name):
        cls = object.__getattribute__(self, 'cls')
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj')
        mro = type(obj).__mro__
        mro_above_cls = mro[mro.index(cls)+1:]
        for super_cls in mro_above_cls:
            if hasattr(super_cls, method_name):
                method = getattr(super_cls, method_name)
                return functools.partial(method, self)
```

Note that you don't have to call this from a method at all. You could do this:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print('A')


class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print('B')

a = A()
b = B()

super(B, b).f()      # prints: A
my_super(B, b).f()   # prints: A
```

### What about the version without arguments?

`super(Maze, self).__init__()` was very explicit, but almost all of Python code always used current class and self as arguments, so Python 3 made it easier by providing a magic `super()` which knows what you want.